# How to pass multiple dynamic headers and a request body to make a rest call in spring integration

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-http

**MyGateway(defined in service-interface) is a Interface will contain one request body(JsonFormat) which I will be passing it in http-outbound-gateway for rest call**

```
<!-- Gateway -->
    <int:gateway id="requestGateway" 
                 service-interface="com.spring.example.MyGateway"
                 default-request-channel="requestChannel12345"/>
    
    <int:channel id="requestChannel12345"/>
    

    
<bean id="methodInsideService"    class="com.spring.example.ServiceImpl"/>
```

**Using below Service-Activator I created one model class which will contains values of headers so that I can use dynamic headers while doing a rest call  ---> below**

```
<int:service-activator input-channel="requestChannel12345"
output-channel="responseChannel1234567" 
ref="methodInsideService" 
method="methodExample"/>

<bean id="clientHttpRequestFactory" class="org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory"/>
```

**Here I am accepting request channel(responseChannel1234567) as outpt-channel(responseChannel1234567) of dynamic headers response ---> here my actual json request overwritten with headers payload which I am creating to use it as dynamic header values**

```
<int:chain input-channel="responseChannel1234567" >
     <int:header-enricher>
     <int:header name="header1"  expression="payload.getheader1()" ></int:header>
     <int:header name="header2" expression="payload.getheader2()" ></int:header>
     <int:header name="header3" expression="payload.getheader3()" ></int:header>
     
     </int:header-enricher>
     <int-http:outbound-gateway 
     id="requestGateway" 
     url="http://localhost/test?queryParam1={queryParam1}&amp;queryParam2={queryParam2}&amp;queryParam3={queryParam3}"
     http-method="POST"
     request-factory="clientHttpRequestFactory" 
     header-mapper="headerMapper12345"
     expected-response-type="java.lang.String">
     <int-http:uri-variable name="queryParam1" expression="payload.getqueryParam1()"/>
     <int-http:uri-variable name="queryParam2" expression="payload.getqueryParam2()"/>
     <int-http:uri-variable name="queryParam3" expression="payload.getqueryParam3()"/>
     </int-http:outbound-gateway>
     
     </int:chain>
    <bean id="headerMapper12345" class="org.springframework.integration.http.support.DefaultHttpHeaderMapper">
     <property name="outboundHeaderNames" value="HTTP_REQUEST_HEADERS, header1,header2,header3" />
     <property name="userDefinedHeaderPrefix" value="" /></bean>
     
    
     
</beans>
```

**Now My Question is how to pass multiple headers(dynamic will pass at code level),multiple query-params(dynamic at code level) and request body(JSON Format) to make a rest call to other services.
Request body we can pass from Interface, but how to pass the headers and query params from interface or using service-activator and then configure xml accordingly to make a rest http outbound gateway call to other rest endpoint.
Thanks in advance**

Answer (score 0):

The question is not clear and requires some details to reveal what exactly are you doing and what are your expectations.

The request body is mapped from the message `payload` by default.
The underlying `RestTemplate` is going to use its `HttpMessageConverter`s to serialize such a body to respective data presentation over the network.

The headers are mapped from the message to the HTTP request according these rules:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/http.html#http-header-mapping

So, if you have some set of headers before sending to this HTTP channel adapter, you can specify their names in the `mapped-request-headers`. Or just use `*` to map all the headers.

The `<header-enricher>` can be configured with the `ref` and `method` to populate something dynamic map of headers:

```
    <xsd:attribute name="ref" type="xsd:string">
        <xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:documentation>
                Reference to an Object to be invoked for header values.
                The 'method' attribute is required
                along
                with this.
            </xsd:documentation>
            <xsd:appinfo>
                <tool:annotation kind="ref"/>
            </xsd:appinfo>
        </xsd:annotation>
    </xsd:attribute>
    <xsd:attribute name="method" type="xsd:string">
        <xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:documentation>
                Method to be invoked on the referenced Object as specified by the
                'ref' attribute. The method
                should return a Map with String-typed keys.
            </xsd:documentation>
            <xsd:appinfo>
                <tool:annotation>
                    <tool:expected-method type-ref="@ref"/>
                </tool:annotation>
            </xsd:appinfo>
        </xsd:annotation>
    </xsd:attribute>
```

https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/message-transformation.html#header-enricher

Comment: I have updated the code as well and what I am trying to achieve. Could you please take a look and help me here.  Thank You